# jQuery, removing brackets from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string like `(12.131883, -68.84942999999998)` and with using `.replace()`  I wish to remove the brackets, or get the values between the brackets. A simple `latlon = latlon.replace('(',' '')` is not working.

Also tried it with `latlon.replace(/\(.*?\)\s/g, '')` but no luck.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: How is `"(12.131883, -68.84942999999998)".replace('(', '');` not working ? Any error ? I just tried it in the console and it works just fine..

Comment: Use `substr`, `var str = '(12.131883, -68.84942999999998)';
str.substr(1, str.length -2);`

Comment: OR `str.replace(/\(|\)/g, '')` OR `str.replace(/[()]/g, '')` OR `str.match(/[^()]/g);` Choose whichever you like

Comment: Tushar, many thanx. Something this stupid I overlooked.

Comment: @AlvinBakker Glad to help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `substring`:

```
var myString = "(12.131883, -68.84942999999998)";
var latlong = myString.substring(1, myString.indexOf(')'));
```

Or:

```
var myString = "(12.131883, -68.84942999999998)";
var latlong = myString.substring(myString.indexOf('(') + 1, myString.indexOf(')'));
```

Comment: In the second code, you assume that braces can be anywhere in the string(_which is wrong, see the example string in question_), and if so, you're just capturing the string between `(` and `)` Ex. `443 (123, 444) 989`, Also the question title `removing brackets from string`, why not just `str.substr(1, str.length -2)`, this will work for the string in question, or replace as shown in my comments

Comment: Please feel free to add the above solutions in the answer,(_I think using the substring from 1 to length - 2 is best solution among those others_) :), and of course, if you think that'll improve answer

Answer (score 1):

You can get them in an array with:

```
var latlon = "(12.131883, -68.84942999999998)";
var ll = latlon.match(/[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+/g)
console.log(ll) // returns ["12.131883", "-68.84942999999998"]
```

Comment: Why such a complicated regex just to remove braces? `var str = '(12.131883, -68.84942999999998)';
str.substr(1, str.length -2);`

Comment: @Tushar - I didn't think it was very complex. It just pulls real numbers.

Comment: I mean you could just have replaced `()`, using ragex `str.replace(/\(|\)/g, '')`;

Comment: @Tushar - yes but that would only have removed the parenthesis while this separates the numbers into an array.

Comment: @AlvinBakker Glad to help :)

Comment: @j08691 I think there is misunderstanding here, _I wish to remove the brackets, or get the values between the brackets_ OP here just mean that he wants to get the string without brackets, he didn't mention `array`, he just mean `12.131883, -68.84942999999998` **string**

Comment: Ah, well I'll leave this as-is in case the OP needs to actually do anything with the individual values. Thanks.

Comment: Please feel free to add the above solutions in the answer,(_I think using the substring from 1 to length - 2 is best solution among those others_) :), and of course, if you think that'll improve answer